# Tensorflow Profiler session tear down and training stopped

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, nvidia, imageai

I am trying to train an object detection model using ImageAI library and here is my code.

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory='Datasets/hololens')
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=['hololens'], batch_size=4, num_experiments=100,
                       train_from_pretrained_model='pretrained-yolov3.h5')
trainer.trainModel()
```

However, the training just keeps stopping/pausing/hanging halfway. It would stop right after showing an error saying "Profiler session tear down" as shown below:

> 2/480 [..............................] - ETA: 4:51 - loss: 183.8092 -
> yolo_layer_loss: 25.4697 - yolo_layer_1_loss: 50.0500 -
> yolo_layer_2_loss: 96.7067 2021-07-30 14:32:31.192212: I
> tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:71] Profiler session
> collecting data. 2021-07-30 14:32:31.196004: I
> tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1487] CUPTI
> activity buffer flushed 2021-07-30 14:32:31.449851: I
> tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_collector.cc:228]
> GpuTracer has collected 5713 callback api events and 5681 activity
> events.  2021-07-30 14:32:31.558638: I
> tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:172] Profiler session
> tear down

I'm using GTX 1080Ti, Tensorflow 2.4.1, CUDA v11.
I've been training image classification models completely fine but when I try to run this object detection model training, this problem happens.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Can you provide the Tensorflow profiler code to investigate the root cause of this error